# Jquery html() and Internet Explorer Issue

Tags: jquery, windows, internet-explorer

The JS script:

```
function ShowUploadingAnimation()
{
    $('#info_msg').html("<div style=\"padding-top: 15px; height: 50px;\" align=\"center\"><img id=\"uploading-img\" /></div>");
    $("#uploading-img").attr({ src: "images/uploading.gif", alt: "Uploading" });
}
```

And the html usage:

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="ShowUploadingAnimation();">
<div id="info_msg"></div>
```

So my issue is the following: This method works ok in Firefox, but in Internet Explorer the gif file is loaded, but it's not animated, just static... showing only a random frame each time the button is clicked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known issue with ie and animated gif's when showing/hiding images whilst during xhr calls & file uploads.
There are lots of solutions given here on a [Ricks Strahl blog post](http://west-wind.com/weblog/ShowPost.aspx?id=1227) in the comments. Maybe one of them will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Easy trick would be put this into iframe. Instead of <img src=''> use <iframe src=''></iframe>.

Comment: That's using a bazooka to kill a fly

Comment: That's solving the problem without getting mad ;)

Comment: True, but it's still a very bad solution to the problem